# Unread (unget) to a BSD socket?

Tags: linux, sockets

My C program has read (using *read(2)* or *recv(2)*) a few bytes from a TCP socket on Linux. Is it possible to push these bytes back so that subsequent *read(2)* and *recv(2)* calls (issued deeply inside a library which I don't control) will read them again?

I know about the *MSG_PEEK* flag of *recv(2)*, and I'm going to use it as a workaround if pushing back turns out to be impossible.

Comment: You should do that in the buffering inside your application, not ask the linux kernel to do it.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Your suggestion is impossible to implement in my use case. see the *issued deeply inside a library which I don't control* clause in the question.

Comment: If you control the call to the "recv" api, then why can't you wrap those calls with your own buffering layer (as per what Basile said)?  If you have the ability to pass MSG_PEEK to the recv call, you should be able to implement your own wrapper on top of recv?  Right?

Comment: @selbile: I intended to say in the original question that I control the 1st *recv(2)*, but not the 2nd one. So your suggestion doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Hmmm... so it is the case, that your code also creates the TCP socket connection and passes the resulting socket to the library?  If so, that opens up the opportunity for tunneling.  Let me know if this is the case, and I'll write up an answer.  cnicutar's answer does look highly compelling, however.

Comment: Also would be great if you explained the architecture between the app, the socket, and the library. Who creates the socket?  Is it a listen socket or connected socket? More details on the code flow would be great.

Comment: @selbie: It's a connected socket and my code creates it, and then passes it to the library. Thank you for suggesting tunneling. There is no need to give more details, I can implement tunneling. But tunneling is just a workaround, it's not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm asking for seems to be impossible. I ended up calling recv() with the flag `MSG_PEEK`. This will make the subsequent recv() or recvmsg() call in the library read the same data.

Without any other calls I can use it to conveniently look ahead only a single byte. Let's suppose I needed to look ahead 2 bytes. I'd call `recv(fd, buf, 2, MSG_PEEK)`. If 1 out of the 2 bytes have already arrived, then recv would return immediately, no matter how many times I call it. I can use *epoll_ctl* with `EPOLLIN | EPOLLET` to wait for the 2nd byte. If I want to know if there was an EOF afterwards, I need `EOPLLIN | EPOLLET | EPOLLRDHUP`. (Please note that `EPOLLHUP` won't be returned on EOF.) So by using `epoll_ctl` I can avoid calling *recv* in a busy, polling loop to read the 2nd byte.

I've just verified on my Linux system that I can peek about 900 kB to the socket this way by default. (`SO_RECVBUF` is 1 MB for me by default, decreasing it with *setsockopt* seems to decrease how much can be received, but not by a consistent amount. Maybe I decrease it too late?)

Even the combination of `MSG_PEEK` and `EPOLLET` is a workaround, because they still don't let me unread arbitrary bytes to the socket. All they let me do is peeking at the bytes already arrived without consuming them.

Comment: You might be able to add the fd to an epoll set in EPOLLET (edge-triggered) mode to wait for N bytes -- if you don't like what you recv, wait for the next epoll event before trying recv again.

Comment: @anthonyrisinger: Thanks for suggesting EPOLLET, it works as you have described it.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to change the workflow such that you don't need to read and then push back data. It just seems way ugly to read something twice (I agree it could be legitimate).

But if this is not possible or very hard, you could hijack the `read` and `recv` system calls using `LD_PRELOAD` (`dlsym`).

Comment: +1, Wow, I have never heard of LD_PRELOAD before, nice to know that exists (though I agree with you about the best option)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `LD_PRELOAD`, it can save the day in some cases. However, in my case the output has to be a statically linked binary, so `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @pts I don't have much experience with linker tricks but are you sure you can't fool that library into calling a symbol from your own ?

Comment: I don't think you can statically link the read/recv calls into a binary - they are always dyanmically linked, right? (I'm not booted into my linux partition to validate...)

Comment: @selbie: gcc -static links read(), recv() and everything else statically.